# How to pass argumens between BottomNavigationItem in Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottomnavigationview, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a problem. Could you please help me?
I have a Jetpack Compose botton navigation where I need to pass arguments between screens. How do I do it with if I use BottomNavigationItem?

```
BottomNavigation(
    backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.grey),
    contentColor = Color.Black
) {
    items.forEach { item ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = { Icon(painterResource(id = item.icon), contentDescription = item.route) },
            selectedContentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.yellow),
            unselectedContentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
            alwaysShowLabel = true,
            selected = currentRoute == item.route,
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(item.route) {
                    navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { screen_route ->
                        popUpTo(screen_route) {
                            saveState = true
                        }
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why you would like to do this? I feel like we're fixing symptoms, not root causes here

Comment: What is the correct way to do BottomNavigation in Compose then?

Comment: Navigation itself looks sensible, i'm only wondering in which situation you'd need to pass data between bottom sheets

Answer (score 0):

You have various options for exchanging data between different screens. One common approach is to utilize a SharedViewModel shared among multiple screens.

Passing the view model directly to the composable, which is not recommended.

```
@Composable
fun MyNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {

    composable("home") {
         HomeScreen(navController, viewModel)
    }
    composable("dashboard") {
         DashboardScreen(navController, viewModel) }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can access the activity context view model within each screen by

```
val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel(LocalContext.current as ComponentActivity)
```